# How to keep the peace after an attempt to colonize an inhabited planet?

Tags: aliens, space-colonization, diplomacy

**We messed up.**

Space colonization is tricky. Sometimes, things go awfully wrong with space colonization. This is the year 2451 and we've just had a failed colonizing expedition, with grave consequences. After 16 years of travel, the expedition misaligned the lander before entering the planet's atmosphere and almost all colonists died.

But.. that's not the only issue..

**An alien email arrived**

And after the crash, we got this alien email, on our company channels,

*Earthlings,*

*We have a problem. There's this boy from Earth on our planet now, 13 years old, sole survivor of your expedition.
He "landed" 6 days ago.. your primitive ship's log sais most crew were in hibernation, when the ship entered our atmosphere. The log also indicated they sought to colonize our planet, with some 40 of your Earth people. We regret to inform you 38 are missing now, almost certainly evaporated during the accident. On the surface, we did find the remains of one of your copilots, but our genetic sequencers did not succeed in getting all the pieces in place, so we regret to inform you 39 human lives were lost. But as these people apparently set out to colonize, we'd like to remind you of our presence, and we have sent a ship, to make sure there are no further misunderstandings..*

*Regards,
Tzlotuun Hoyran, General*

General. A military rank. "primitive ship". They decoded our logs. No mension of the boy.

The approaching alien ship has been detected, it will arrive on Earth, in 22 days (!!)

**We are inexperienced. We have had close encounters, but until now, they were quite friendly. What would be an appropriate protocol, a first diplomatic step, to avoid confrontation ?**

Comment: Are you looking for a company's response or a government's response?  AFAIK- it is illegal (in US) to make 1st Contact.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the bold question.

Comment: "OOopps, sorry.  Navigation error."

Comment: It looks like you're asking about the decisions of a specific in world entity. Such questions are a story based question not a question about creating a fact of the world.

Comment: E-mail sits atop a zillion layers of technological standards, which must all be in place for e-mail to happen. Technological standards are in the nature of international treaties. If you got an e-mail from them, this means that there is a communications network in place. If a communication network is in place, this means that Earth already has some sort of diplomatic channels with them. Since Earth already had some sort of communication with them and yet Earth sent a colony ship, this means that Earth is at war with them. There is no peace to keep. We started the war. *We are the baddies.*

Comment: @AlexP or they recovered some of the ships communication systems.

Comment: Yes yes yes @AlexP all clear.. only issue is.. we don't actually know how they sent that e-mail. We have investigated our company logs, their email originates from a known Martian provider, nothing special. They appear to have registered a free  e-mail address there.. Of course we have put effort in making sure we don't have a (human !) impostor, behind this email.

Comment: this needs a lot more context, what is the human tech level, how was the planet examined in the first place? also "oversaw" means managed which means they knew about the natives, did you mean "missed"

Comment: @John your questions are relevant, but this is an emergency..  No time for elaborate descriptions. We can stand our ground on space travel, we do have some weaponry too, but their ships are apparently 200x as fast as ours and they have no issue writing us e-mails in English with euuhmm.. subtly threatening language.. Experts are looking into it, we have 21 days. They are technologically superior, everyone agrees about that.

Comment: @Goodies I don't think you understand how questions work here, we as posters need inofrmation  to make answers and your story coherent, how the planet was explored will drastically change aspects of the question. Questions here are OOC.

Comment: I don't see that anything actually hostile happened here. The humans set off *intending* to colonize an uninhabited planet; that much would be obvious from their logs. They crashed before they could realize and react to the fact that the it was not uninhabited. The aliens can *assume* whatever they want about how the crew *would* have reacted but it's just that, an assumption that's entirely driven by their own character and biases.

Comment: @John I added an explanation about how/why we overlooked the clues we had.

Comment: (government talking) @Cadence indeed.. it seems *not* hostile, but it is very clear about one aspect: they have sent a ship "to remind us of their presence". We want to be cautious and not provoke them in any way. How to put the email in such a way, it will buy us time.. We need information about their ship and their capabilities. We won't hand over planet Earth to them on the first communication.

Comment: (governnent talking) this communication channel was closed suddenly ! Where do we find the interstellar invasion experts now...

Comment: Asking how to "write" a mail to an individual seems more like a work for Writing SE. Even if said mail is a politicostory one ^^. Now, if you are creating a protocol in approaching unknown species, that'd be another matter, but given the ultra-specific circumstances, it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: @Tortliena yes if I had put (only) a formal protocol question, it would have been more consistent with WB guidelines, you are right about that. Such a protocol would also be a valid answer in this topic, I would vote it up and (maybe) acknowledge as answer. The above is my way to put such a question. But apparently some peer mods only want to see *explicit questions*, with a certain (very deterministic) format. I am not good at that, maybe that is why I have only 2 questions and many answers. When answering, I have the freedom of weaving a *story* around it. For questions, it is not accepted.

Comment: @Goodies Taking it as a protocol, you could have handled it in your storytelling with something in the like "Alas, the foreign life team lost the com' protocol A4B96Z on taking contact with very highly-advanced species following diplomatic incidents. Could you help us retrieve it and therefore help us in this tricky situation?". It won't be perfect to all eyes, but you start shifting from story to world :).

Comment: I could remove the introduction.. see what happens..

Comment: It is silly to attempt to settle on an inhabited planet before the natives have been contacted and defeated if necessary to end any opposition to the settleing.  So a small expedition of 40 persons wouldn't seem like an invastion force sent to defeat an inhabited planet, but instead an attempt to settle on on planet thought to be uninhabited.  In fact the aliens might assume that such a small expedition would be for exploration, not colonization.

Comment: - mods thx for reopen.. @M.A.Golding we do agree this alien species, able to communicate with another species on a diplomatic level, would know that. The email we got from them is in English, in fact it is *not* directly hostile. However, our foreign affairs advisors insist on a risk analysis, before we put an answer. They are a month away from Earth. For them, it is a shorter time, but not *really* short. They have to put effort in sending a ship. And we don't really believe a ship is sent only to avoid *"further misunderstandings.."*. We are working on a protocol, we will keep you informed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A meeting place.**

Aliens are coming.  They are fast.  If they can move that fast and they are warlike we are toast.  Other governments need to know aliens are coming so they don't do something stupid when they detect them.

Humbly apologize.  Thank them for rescuing the boy and trying to help the copilot.  Note that you are interested in learning more about the genetic sequencer.  Give them coordinates on Earth that they will understand (perhaps a map) and arrange to meet them there.  Invite representatives from other governments.  Have gifts.  Cross fingers.

Comment: .. and carry a big stick.  (You also might want to meet somewhere not-earth.)

Comment: (government talking) yes thanks mr Wilk, we have told the UN yesterday. We'll have to make some excuse for the colonization. *And* we cross our fingers !

Comment: (government talking) We have decided to follow this line. They are clearly superior in space travel, we cannot hide our disadvantage from them. We will humbly apologize and thank them for their efforts. Also we need to try to find a proper way to ask them about the boy's whereabouts in such a way, they would not be offended. The sequencer is an interesting idea as well, we can show them we are eager to learn about that technology. First things first.. the protocol we'll have to follow, our response.. *and* the boy.

Answer (score 2):

Simple claim that is was all a misunderstanding. That you didn't know the planet was inhabited. Offer a small contemsation in exchange for the boy and everything thing should be alright.

Just in case send out your entire fleet to as a Friendly excort for the alien ship. Just as a reminder who runs this galaxy.

Comment: (government talking) Thanks for your input. The boy is our primary concern atm. We don't know if he is on the ship. We don't know if the boy is a hostage or not. We are already underways. *What a mess..* this company will be out of business soon. Maybe we'll have to put an email we announce we will punish the company ? Maybe you're right we should offer something in exchange for the boy..

Comment: @Goodies I don't think punishing the company will be necessary after all the lose of those the alien killed should be punishment enough perhaps if the aliens insist on it as a condition of get the boy back.

Comment: Right now the humanity must more carefully apologetic but at same time it doesn't want to appear weak or easily bullied. So you want to give enough to appear regretful but not enough to feel afraid especially when the boys status is unclear.

Comment: (government talking) We have decided to *not* base the protocol on your proposal. One of our anthropology experts indicated that offering a reward for saving the boy could be interpreted by them as putting up a price for the boy. We don't know their culture, we don't know if the boy is on board their ship. Also, there were grave objections from the part of Defense, against sending in the fleet. Too much risk and we would show all our cards.

Comment: @Goodies what would you do instead.

Answer (score 2):

(government)

**(Proceedings)**

With your inputs sofar, we have devised an approach, that would respect the thruth (the error is on our side) and we'll show our gratitude for the report and their efforts to save our crew member.

There is no time for a formal protocol, we will have to put that in place when all ends well. For now, our psychology experts have advised us to answer the email in the same style, that is polite and informal,

*Dear General,*

*We regret the misunderstanding about your presence. We should have investigated further before landing, to make sure we would *not* claim a planet that is rightfully yours. We thank you for your attempts to rescue our crew member, and the detailed account you have provided.*

*We hope all is well with the Earth boy. His parents are looking forward to see him soon. We expect to welcome you in 21 of our days, with military salute and in the presence of our leaders, and the boys parents. We look forward to the acquaintance, more information will follow later about our preferred time and place.*

*In order to prove good intent on our side, we have decided to provide you with a gift. The gift was sent toward your ship in a small probe and it  contains some very useful, Carbon-based materials.*

*Kind regards,
Earth's government*

We had most discussion about the part concerning the boy. We can't be sure of culture (parents), on the other hand we can't speculate either.. it is difficult to find a way to give them an incentive, to say anything about the boy. We really want to know if the boy is aboard their ship and we will regard any promise about the boy as a confirmation of peaceful intent on their side. By announcing the parents to be present to welcome them, we hope to put some pressure to hear more. Is the boy on the ship ?

About the meeting location.. we have not decided yet, who will be present and where it will be. We don't want (or we can't) pin them down on any landing location, but we have indicated that *we would decide* where to meet them. When they accept that, we will also regard that as peaceful.

The gift consists of several rolled up samples of our best grapheme foil.. and also a highly accurate diamond lens, in a small wooden box. Carbon is quite rare on their planet, but it can be found. There are traces on the surface and there exists gaseous carbon (as CO2) in their atmosphere. We hope (expect) they may be unaware of the many applications of solid Carbon.

Comment: One thing that really stands out about this answer is the part about solid carbon... if we know the chemical composition of the planet we are going to, then we can guess what things we have that could be seen as valuable, exotic, or even or even technologically advanced to them.  That is a great way of providing them with a worthy gift, but also a very big risk.  If they know they are more advanced than us in most ways, but that we have a resource that they would really like to have, we could easily go the way of the Incans and their gold

Comment: They have that info already. They found the remains of our colonization ship, a black box with its logs intact. These logs told them we had been on a 16 year travel to that planet. Then, they send a ship toward us that can reach Earth in a month. Their advantage is quite obvious, I'm afraid.. they already know we're at least a century behind them in spacecrafts. But we're not going to show them any other technology, until we know their intention. We don't have any illusion we would win, when an armed conflict would occur (the minister of the Environment suggested we'd sell them our excess CO20

Comment: This is really good. Still think you should send the "escort "

Comment: @BryanMcClure we'll need a week margin at least, to send our ships out.. Maybe we'll *have to*, but before we decide, we'll wait for a response to above message.. There's 19 days, we'll keep you informed via here.

Answer (score 0):

(government)

**Proceedings**

The alien ship has materialized (?) at L2, we did not get a response to our mail. Scientists have proposed the aliens could not receive our mail in time, because we don't know how to do their FTL tricks. Our email landed at the server, 2 light years before they arrived. The server would send it over, but the message has never reached them.

They are past L2 now, approaching Earth on impulse.. and we still have no reason to assume the boy is on the ship. We resent the message and got the following response,

*Earthlings,*

*We hail Earth, may the Xyluph enhance (?) your Ytug. In two days, we will land on the back side of your moon, we expect your diplomats and fleet to welcome us as promised. Please indicate the level of Tgluip, so we can enter your ship safely.*

*Regards, Tzlotuun Hoyran, General*

.. we regard this as positive and negative. They seem to wish us luck, but same time they seem to expect us to lower our shields. We are not sure what is expected of us (please help.. Tgluip ??), we stationed a diplomatic  delegation in one of our star ships in moon orbit.

We'll keep you informed !